# Jenkins/Gerrit stream events - job triggered on newly created branch

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I am using Jenkins in combination with the Git and Gerrit plugins. I would like to trigger a job on `Ref Updated`. However, I need to understand if the action behind this event is the creation of a new branch. If it is, then I will execute my shell script, otherwise not.

As far as I understood, this info is available in the Gerrit's event json response, but I do not know how to consume this json object via Jenkins in the first place.

Is there a way to achieve this easily via Jenkins (maybe something in the interface I missed)? Or is there another way to monitor the creation of a new branch while still in the Jenkins/Gerrit plugin environment?

Comment: I think this event happens when for example a direct push is made on a ref. but I am not sure that a creation of a branch can be counted as a ref update.

Comment: My plain job gets triggered every time I create a new remote branch (on the Gerrit interface), as well as when I delete it and perform other actions. The event I specified is `Rep Updated` and the specified branch is any branch.

Comment: edit: what I meant with "plain" was "blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just recalled there are a bunch of Gerrit environmental variables which are available to use in the building script,[image]

namely these ones. I will just have to check if `GERRIT_OLDREV` is equal to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and if so, it would mean the branch is newly created (for reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323175/git-hook-add-a-new-file-to-repo-if-a-new-branch-is-created)). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCuXe.png) is the picture I attached in full size.